# SUM of N non-zero preceding rows in SQL table

Tags: sql, hana

I have the following table:

```
DATE    , EMPLOYEE_ID, ILL
1.1.2016, 101,         0
1.1.2016, 102,         1
2.1.2016, 101,         1
2.1.2016, 102,         1
3.1.2016, 101,         0
3.1.2016, 102,         0
```

And I need to write an SQL code to create a new column which would calculate a number of preceding (considering `DATE`) non-zero integers in the `ILL` column to a new column.

And that must be for each employee separately.

The reason is that I need to find out how many days has an employee been ill (1 for absence in the `ILL` column) before said date.

Is this even possible to do in SQL?

I am currently trying to alter the query from https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/181773/sum-of-previous-n-number-of-columns-based-on-some-category
but I am not having success yet.

OUTPUT I WANT:

```
DATE,     EMPLOYEE_ID, PREVIOUS
1.1.2016, 101,         0
1.1.2016, 102,         0
2.1.2016, 101,         0
2.1.2016, 102,         1
3.1.2016, 101,         1
3.1.2016, 102,         2
4.1.2016, 101,         0
4.1.2016, 102,         0
```

This is data prep for my master's thesis. I am using SAP HANA Studio.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, edit your question and show the results you want.

Comment: What database are you using ? This is important because the leading databases (Oracle, SQL-Server, Postgresql) have analytic functions that make queries like that very easy.

Answer (score 2):

You would do this by assigning a group number to each group separated by 0s.  Then, you would use `row_number()` within the group.

You can calculate the group number using a cumulative sum.  So, the query looks like:

```
select t.*,
       (case when ill = 1
             then row_number() over (partition by employee_id, grp, ill order by date)
        end) as ill_day_counter
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when ill = 0 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by employee_id order by date) as grp
      from t
     ) t;
```

Comment: I did not find out why, but this querry prints out an output of 2 for the first day of absence in the new column. However simply substracting from the new column solves this issue. Thank you a lot!

Comment: @SgtMarmite . . . That is one fix.  The reason is because the group starts on the last `0` record.  I added `grp` into the `partition by`.  That should fix the problem in a saner way.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a cumulative (windowing) count:

```
SELECT date,
       employee_id,
       ill, 
       COUNT(CASE ill WHEN 1 THEN 1 END) OVER 
            (PARTITION BY employee_id
             ORDER BY date ASC
             ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT_ROW)
FROM   mytable
```

Comment: This code almost works. It adds up to total sum of absent days (ILL=1), however the counter does not go to 0 when an employee goes to work again (ILL=0).
Could there be a fix?

Answer (score 0):

A simple self join will help to solve this problem without only using SUM() and GROUP BY as follows

```
select 
    t1.date, 
    t1.EMPLOYEE_ID, 
    t1.ill, 
    coalesce(sum(t2.ill),0) as previous
from testdata as t1
left join testdata as t2
    on t1.EMPLOYEE_ID = t2.EMPLOYEE_ID and
       t1.date > t2.date
group by t1.date, t1.EMPLOYEE_ID, t1.ill
order by t1.date, t1.EMPLOYEE_ID;
```

An alternative query can be as follows which gives the same result as above

```
SELECT date,
       employee_id,
       ill, 
       coalesce(
       SUM(ill) OVER 
            (PARTITION BY employee_id
             ORDER BY date ASC
             ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
       ), 0) as Previous
FROM   testdata
```

Just a note, as I understand from your question; you seem to ask for number of consecutive days that the employee was ill before that day. Am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the number of consecutive ill days just before the current date for an employee, followin SQL query could be used

```
with newdata as (
select 
    *,
    case 
        when ill = 1 and lag(ill,1,0) over (partition by EMPLOYEE_ID order by date) = 0 then 1 end as illdays
from testdata
), empdata as (
select
    date, EMPLOYEE_ID, ill,
    case when ill = 1 and lag(ill,1,0) over (partition by EMPLOYEE_ID order by date) = 1 then coalesce(lag(illdays,1,0) over (partition by EMPLOYEE_ID order by date),0)+1 else illdays end as illdays
from newdata
)
select
date, EMPLOYEE_ID, ill,
coalesce( lag(illdays,1,0) over (partition by EMPLOYEE_ID order by date), 0) as previous
from empdata
order by EMPLOYEE_ID, date;
```

Before going into details and explaining the SQL query, here is the output of the execution of above SqlScript

[image]

First of all, instead of sub-select statements I used Common Table Expression [CTE expression in SQLScript](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-multiple-cte-syntax-sql-cte-example-in-sql-server-2008.aspx) using WITH clauses

I frequently used [SQL Lag() function](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/lag-function-in-sql-server-2012-for-previous-values.aspx) in my code to read previous records in given order using Partition By and Order By clauses following Lag() function. Since Lag() function is a standard SQL function, you can use it on different database platforms

The query actually finds a starting point in newdata CTE and store illdays column.

Then I update this value in following empdata CTE. This part identifies repeating illness days following one after each other

Last CTE is used to display illness days and prepare final output

I hope it helps